# MacOS Accessibility noValue error when accessing kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute

Tags: cocoa, accessibility, accessibility-api, accessibility-inspector

I am working on a MacOS app which uses accessibility API to detect text fields.

I have done so far and I was preparing to launch my app. It works perfectly on my Mac. Then I decided to share the app with some of my friends for testing purposes.

Then I noticed after getting accessibility permission while accessing kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute return `AXError = 25212` which is `AXError.noValue`.

The interesting part is it can detect URL fields of Google Chrome and Safari but no more.

Here is my code for finding a focused element

```
extension pid_t {

    var focussedField: AnyObject? {
        let axUIElementApplication = AXUIElementCreateApplication(self)
        var focussedField: AnyObject?
        let result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(axUIElementApplication, kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute as CFString, &focussedField)
        guard result == .success else {
            logger("Failed to get focussedField \(result.rawValue)", source: .pid)
            Events.PIDExtensionFocusedFieldError(code: result.rawValue).sendEvent()
            return nil
        }
        return focussedField
    }
}
```

I am observing front most applications with these pieces of observer.

```
cancellable = NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter
    .publisher(for: NSWorkspace.didActivateApplicationNotification)
    .map { notification -> NSRunningApplication? in
        notification.userInfo?[NSWorkspace.applicationUserInfoKey] as? NSRunningApplication
    }
    .sink { [weak self] application in
    // assigning application and other stuffs
    }
```

I have searched for some questions and tried to debug via logs and Accessibility Inspector.

Here is the twist: After launching `Accessibility Inspector` works perfectly on every buggy device.

Comment: Does Accessibility Inspector work perfectly or does your app work perfectly after launching Accessibility Inspector? Where does `pid` come from? Do the non-working apps support accessibility and do they have a focused UI element?

Comment: Hi @Willeke my app works perfectly after launching Accessibility Inspector.
This is a property of pid_t. I have created it like that `extension pid_t { var focussedField: AnyObject? {`. No, I am not trying to access non-working apps.  
I am listening `NSWorkspace.didActivateApplicationNotification` and observing `NSWorkspace.applicationUserInfoKey` from notification userInfo. I am editing my question with these pieces of information.